# Can't stop the looping function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to stop the looping function, but it did not work

```
function ref(){
  var iin=setTimeout(ref,1000);
}

$('#start').click(function(){ ref(); });    
$('#stop').click(function(){clearTimeout(iin);});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the variable outside the function. Called a global variable. And assign it inside your function like so:

```
var timer;
function go(){
/// STUFF
timer=setTimeout(some_function, 1000);
}

$('#start').click(function(){go();});

$('#stop').click(function(){clearTimeout(timer);});
```

Comment: this is correct, but you generally want to declare global variables by using `window.iin = setTimeout(ref,(scdy/2)-100);` so they're not to be confused with scoped variables. This will also prevent your code from breaking if it is moved into an IIFE.

Comment: @Aleksov you have the variable `scdy` that is undefined from your post. Have you defined this variable yet? Not sure what your problem is. @jbabey is correct about the `window`, it is not required but recommended.

Comment: @StevePeak you are declaring `iin` but using `inn`

Comment: Either I'm very stupid or something I do not understand ... `var iin,ref=function(){window.iin=setTimeout(ref,1000);
};`
Still not work...

Comment: That's what I did, but the function `go()` is still running
`var timer;
function go(){
/// STUFF
timer=setTimeout(go(), 1000);
}

$('#start').click(function(){go();});

$('#stop').click(function(){clearTimeout(timer);});`

Comment: try `setTimeout(go, 1000)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AdusA/4/ That's what I had in mind, but in my case it does not work for some reason ...

Answer (score 5):

your variable `iin` is not accessible inside the `click` event handler. You should make it globally accessible

```
var iin;
function ref(){
    iin = setTimeout(ref,(scdy/2)-100);
}

$('#start').click(function(){ ref(); });

$('#stop').click(function(){ clearTimeout(iin); });
```

Comment: See, Steve Peak has just posted it. follow it.